# What is the difference between the permissions SET_WALLPAPER and SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS on Android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm looking at Android's permissions for setting a wallpaper.

I found the following two permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
```

To understand these permissions, I read [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) but I still couldn't understand the explanation.

What's the difference between `SET_WALLPAPER` and `SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS`?

I want to ask, where are **hints** for setting a wallpaper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not explained well but if you browse the [WallpaperManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager), you'll get the answer.

> **setDisplayPadding** <sup>added in API level 28</sup>
>
> public void setDisplayPadding (Rect padding)
>
> **Specify extra padding that the wallpaper should have outside of the display. That is, the given padding supplies additional pixels the wallpaper should extend outside of the display itself.**
>
> This method requires the caller to hold the permission `Manifest.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS`.
>
> **Requires the `SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS` permission.**

[Emphasis added]

There's also [`suggestDesiredDimensions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#suggestDesiredDimensions(int,%20int)) that requires this permission but that's only if you're implementing a launcher app.

*Basically if you want to be able to set a wallpaper that extends beyond the boundaries of the current view (e.g. wallpaper parallax scrolling), you need this permission to enable that functionality.*